# .htaccess/DNS set folder for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, subdirectory

I have a subdomain/subdirectory problem and am not sure how to solve it. I have tried different .htaccess configurations but none so far have worked.

My site is hosted on shared hosting so some limitations apply.
my directory structure, which is set up this way because of the CMS I'm using, looks like this:

- assets (folder)
- web (folder)
- web-infiniti-brussel (folder)
- .htaccess
- other files and folders

My .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gmsgroup.be$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gmsgroup.be$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
  RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^infiniti-brussel\.gmsgroup\.be
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web-infiniti-brussel/
  RewriteRule (.*) /web-infiniti-brussel/$1 [L]

  Redirect /infiniti-brussel https://infiniti-brussel.gmsgroup.be
</IfModule>
```

This ends up giving me the following error: `The requested URL /web-infiniti-brussel/infiniti-brussel was not found on this server.`

I feel like I might be getting closer but after trying so many different things and not getting any to work I'm not sure what to do next.
I also thought I had to make a new CNAME or A record in my DNS for my subdomains but the support of my hosting said that wasn't necessary (Though they were not of any real help otherwise)

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what are you trying to achieve with your rules, and what url did you try when you got the above error

Comment: The first part is to set my web folder as the root of my hosting, which works, the second part is to (try) to load the content from the web-infiniti-brussel folder  when someone goes to the infiniti-brussel subdmain (This is probably where the problem is). And the last line is to redirect to infiniti-brussel.gmsgroup.be when the load gmsgroup.be/infiniti-brussel. The error I got when I went to infiniti-brussel.gmsgroup.be

Comment: If you remove the `Redirect..` line, does the second part work OK?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I'm not getting the error though, instead I'm getting: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, so it seems like it is trying to do something

Comment: `infiniti-brussel.gmsgroup.be`is pointed to different IP address than `(www.)gmsgroup.be`

Comment: That might be true, I added a DNS setting which probably caused that, I removed it and now when I go to infiniti-brussel.gmsgroup.be I get the previous error `The requested URL /web-infiniti-brussel/infiniti-brussel was not found on this server.` again

Comment: Are there any other Redirects/RewriteRules in .htaccess besides those shown above? Or maybe another .htaccess file in web-infiniti-brussel/ folder?

Comment: Nothing else in the .htaccess and the web-infiniti-brussel folder only has an index.php file. Could the problem be caused by me setting the web folder as the root folder? (I'm not a htaccess pro :/ )